# PHP Invalid Paths

Tags: php

I am having trouble with some of my PHP code.

I have entered a path for my application download directory, however it has stated the **path is invalid**

My code:

```
$destination_file = "C:\folder\new";
$source_file = "C:\entryt.txt";
```

I have tried to echo out the path to check it, it appears part of the string is missing, such as the `\`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using double quotes for your path.

If you wish to use double quotes, you will need to **escape** your backslashes, otherwise you will realise that the characters are missing since they get treated as say `\n`, which is a new line function in PHP.

You can escape like so:

```
$destination_file = "C:\\folder\\new";
```

Alternatively, you can use single quotes and not worry about escaping:

```
$destination_file = 'C:\folder\new';
```